# Is it wrong to say "feel pleasure"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, collocations

I know we can use the collocation [feel satisfaction](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/satisfaction). You can find it in the list of collocations in the link. My question is: Is "feel pleasure" a collocation we can use? I looked at the collocations with "pleasure" on [here,](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pleasure) but "feel pleasure" is not among them. So is it wrong to say "feel pleasure"? Let me make up some sentences that include that phrase:

- I felt pleasure when I first played in front of a crowd.
- A: How do you feel at your new home? B: I just feel pleasure.

Comment: "For us to feel pleasure, we need to open ourselves to life and its surprises." - _Psychology Today_ (Google search)

Comment: 'Feeling pleasure' often refers to a physical sensation; we would say _I am pleased to be in my new home_.

Comment: Do you think this sentence is okay: "I don't feel pleasure playing video games"

Answer (score 3):

*Feel pleasure* often refers to physical sensations and therefore can potentially have sensual or erotic undertones to it.

Try *to be pleased* instead:

> I felt pleasure when I first played in front of a crowd -> I was pleased when I first played in front of a crowd.

> A: How do you feel at your new home? B: I just feel pleasure. -> A: How do you feel at your new home? B: I'm just pleased.

Comment: I don't know, if you try hard enough you can bring the same connotation to "satisfaction." At any rate, there are plenty of chaste results for "pleasure": https://www.google.com/search?q=%22feel+pleasure%22+%22felt+pleasure%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvLFCFZSqfNH1DxG3GWgGuzLkDMchw%3A1634910306008&ei=YcByYd-DPa2eytMPp5S_uA4&oq=%22feel+pleasure%22+%22felt+pleasure%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...33137.36000.0.36299.16.16.0.0.0.0.127.1450.0j13.13.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.1.110...33i299k1.0.oAqvck2JKJg

Comment: Just something to keep in mind.  I would avoid saying "I felt pleasure giving this presentation" in a business setting, for example.

Comment: Do you think this sentence is okay: "I don't feel pleasure playing video games"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use "feel pleasure". Here are some example uses:
[Google ngram viewer *feel pleasure*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feel%20pleasure&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeel%20pleasure%3B%2Cc0)

Click on a date range, and look through the examples.

(Your two examples aren't typical uses of "feel pleasure"; they would more likely be feel satisfied, or excited.)

Comment: (Re following ngram results into Google Books searches: I only just now realized that if you click, not on a date range, but on the phrase itself to the left of the ranges, you search all date ranges without limitation.)

Comment: Do you think this sentence is okay: "I don't feel pleasure playing video games"

Comment: You can say it. Far likelier though, is just "I don't like playing video games."